# Will Maxpayne 3 levels all be the same?

Tags: max-payne-3

So I reached chapter 5 in MaxPayne 3. However I noticed a pattern of going from one place to another and getting ambushed by 10+ guys. Will it become different in the next chapters? No spoilers please.

Comment: You won't have to stop walking or shooting if that's what you're asking.

Comment: The gameplay is so-so and very repetitive. If that doesn't get you, the cutscenes will which seem to go on for 5-10 minutes that you cannot skip... claiming to be loading the whole time... bull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No not really, however I don't find it gets boring, the game play is awesome. There are obviously some differences more sniper scenes and other more difficult situations and enemies. If you didnt like how it was going already you probably wont like the rest of the game.

I played it through twice, loved it.

Comment: Thanks, yes the gameplay is awesome. But its kinda getting repetitive. Still going to finish it though !! Wonder who gave me a  -1 though :(

Comment: @Fendi I am not sure, it wasn't me although i was tempted cause of how much i loved MP3 :p. But i will up vote for you pleasure.